# Making a ServerXMLHTTP with a custom protocol in the URL

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

Here's what I'm trying to do...

```
oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0");
oXMLHTTP.open("GET", "ccte://recservice.com", false);
oXMLHTTP.send();
```

And here is the error I get in return...

> msxml3.dll error '80072ee6'
>   The URL does not use a recognized protocol

It works fine if I make the request using the HTTP protocol (i.e. `http://recservice.com` instead of `ccte://recservice.com`). Is there anything I can do within the IIS configuration to get ServerXMLHTTP requests working with my custom protocol?

Comment: I doubt that error comes from your URL, is not getting that far. It's the ServerXmlHttp that is raising the error, so configuring IIS would have no affect.

Comment: I would be surprised if custom protocols are supported, the clue is in the name ServerXml**Http**. [Frequently asked questions about ServerXMLHTTP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/290761).

Answer (score 2):

While I've not been able to find anything conclusive I would be very surprised if this was supported.

The error

> msxml3.dll error '80072ee6'
>   The URL does not use a recognized protocol

is the first clue as it's the `ServerXmlHttp` object that is raising the error, not IIS or other lower level sources.

Another clue is the name ServerXml**Http**, which tells you this object supports the HTTP protocol *(to by extension to a certain extent HTTPS)*.

This object is not a TCP/IP Client, it's a Web Client so anything over than standard Web Protocols is not going to be supported.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Frequently asked questions about ServerXMLHTTP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/290761)
- [A: Differences between XMLHTTP and ServerXMLHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674814/692942)